# maven jaxws Failed to execute wsgen

Tags: maven, jax-ws

I am using netbeans with maven 3. When I try to compile with jaxws-maven-plugin, I get the following error.

Here is my pom

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>teamWS</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <resourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/classes/wsdl</resourceDestDir>
                        <sei>xyz.timerserver.server.TimeServer</sei>
                        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                        <keep>true</keep>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-MR1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

This is the error message that I get. I tried to add tools.jar using system scope dependency but still no luck

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:1.10:wsgen (teamWS) on project JWSServer: Failed to execute wsgen: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 12):

As a first step, ensure that you're running maven with a correct java version -- **jaxws:wsgen** (1.12) appears to malfunction with **java 7**, in such a case use **java 6**, i.e.:

- if you run it from a shell, `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/6`
- if you're running it from an IDE, specify java version at the IDE start-up time

  - e.g. for **eclipse**, use start-up option `-vm /path/to/java/6`

For me, this solved the `Failed to execute wsgen` caused by `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException`.

Comment: Switching from Java 8 to Java 7 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 10):

Try using updated version of the plugin from JAX-WS commons project.

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
```

Answer (score 3):

The project just went back to MojoHaus so you should use the latest version from [there](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/).

1. <2007: **1.0-1.12** (groupId  *org.codehaus.moj*o)
2. 2007-2015: **2.1-2.3.1** (groupId *org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons*)
3. 2015-today: **>=2.4** (groupId *org.codehaus.mojo*)

> The original code was developed in the Codehaus Mojo project, then as of March 2007, the project moved to jax-ws-commons with version 1.x in org.codehaus.mojo groupId and version 2.x in org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons groupId. **In September 2015, for version 2.4, it went back to MojoHaus (the new home of Codehaus Mojo) in org.codehaus.mojo groupId**

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official example configuration, it is available [here](https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxws-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/it/wsgen/pom.xml).

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>@project.groupId@</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>@project.version@</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsgen</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sei>org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.it.HelloWorldImpl</sei>
                <genWsdl>true</genWsdl> <!-- for demo purpose only, the wepapp does not need those the generated wsdl files-->
                <keep>true</keep>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Please review the dependencies they are using to avoid compilation errors. See the `mvn dependency:tree` output:

```bash
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------< org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:mojo.it.helloworldws >------------
[INFO] Building helloworld 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ mojo.it.helloworldws ---
[INFO] org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:mojo.it.helloworldws:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- jakarta.xml.soap:jakarta.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO]    +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO]    +- jakarta.jws:jakarta.jws-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO]    +- com.sun.xml.ws:policy:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO]    +- org.glassfish.gmbal:gmbal:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.external:management-api:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-basic:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-tf:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-asm:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-dynamic:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-basic-tools:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.glassfish.pfl:pfl-tf-tools:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:jar:1.5.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO]    +- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO]    +- org.glassfish.ha:ha-api:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO]    +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.1.0:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.1:runtime
[INFO]    \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.808 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-15T12:58:08-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```